# Prove that if $n \mid a$ and $n \mid b$ then $n \mid (a+b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

As stated in the title, I need to prove that
if $n \mid a$ and $n \mid b$ then $n \mid (a+b)$.

So far this is what I have:

> Assume that $n \mid a$ and $n \mid b$. Then there exists two integers $d$ and $f$ such that $n \mid a = nd$ and $n \mid b = nf$. I am stumped at this point. I remember there was a rule for something like this but I can't remember the name of it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If n | a then a = nf, and if n | b then b = nd for some integers f & d. Then you can add a & b to get nd + nf. Which then you can factor out the n and get that a + b= n(f+d), which implies that n | a + b

Comment: " n|a = nd " makes no sense, check your definitions

Comment: And this can be generalized to $n|ax+by$, where x and y are integers. It also works for any number of variables.

Comment: @jjagmath it makes sense to me.

Comment: @MJD It doesn't make sense **as definition of $n \mid a$** , which is the current context.

Comment: @jjagmath I agree